# tcgetpgrp function in C

Tags: c, linux, unix, stdio

Syntax:

```
   pid_t tcgetpgrp(int fd);
```

In MAN Page:

> The  function tcgetpgrp() returns the process group ID of the foreground process group on the terminal associated to fd, which must be the controlling terminal of the calling process.`

So, using this function we can get the foreground process of terminal. But I didn't understand which file descriptor is passed to this function. What is the use of file descriptor passed to this function and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6
IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition says :

> **11.1.2 Process Groups**
>
> A terminal may have a foreground process group associated with it.
>   This foreground process group plays a special role in handling
>   signal-generating input characters, as discussed in Special
>   Characters.

`tcgetpgrp` is the function that can give back the ID of this group attached to a given terminal. The parameter must be a file descriptor associated to a terminal, more than this it must be a descriptor of the controlling terminal of the process :

> **11.1.3 The Controlling Terminal**
>
> A terminal may belong to a process as its controlling terminal. Each
>   process of a session that has a controlling terminal has the same
>   controlling terminal.

In short, a controlling terminal is the object that lets you manage jobs in your shell : dispatch CTRL-Z to suspend a job, make a job the foreground one, cancel an job with CTRL-C, etc. A controlling terminal lets you control group of processes attached to this terminal. This control may include : concurrent access to the terminal, session management, foreground/background, etc.

`ctermid` may give you the path of your controlling terminal (`tty` command line does the same). Be aware that the controlling terminal may not be the same as the terminal on which you make your standard I/Os, but in general it is the same. You can then (very commonly) use STDIN_FILENO (and the two others as well). You can also use `isatty` to determine if a file descriptor is associated to a terminal.

Comment: where STDIN_FILENO macro is present. Shall I use 0 instead of this macro?

Comment: You should have STDIN_FILENO available (include `unistd.h`) as you are on Unix system. The standard defines STDIN_FILENO as 0, so yes you may use 0 in place of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just call it like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>

pid_t pid = tcgetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO);
```

Comment: OK. That's Not the problem. My requirement is, what is the use of fd to this function And where it refers to?

Comment: It's just the stdio file number for the process - you can pass `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO`, or `STDERR_FILENO` as appropriate.

Comment: still you didn't understand my question. I already have the answer. My need is why we need to pass STDIN_FILENO as argument. And what is the use of this argument passed to that function.